# Ascension and descent

Tags: etymology

Why is the opposite of 'ascension' still 'descent', and not 'descension'? ([Reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ascension). NB: fully aware the answer may be convention, as it is with many things in English.)

Comment: *Ascension* is not interchangeable with *ascent*; it has philosophical/religious/cosmological connotations, especially in Christianity.

Comment: The word *descension* does indeed exist, though it is less used than its disyllabic brother *descent.*

Comment: Could you perhaps give us an example of a sentence which includes the word 'ascension' which refers to anything other than Christ's ascension into heaven? I am struggling to think of one.

Comment: There is no reason. There is also no assumption of regularity with [derivational morphology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), so there's no reason why the nominalizations of _ascend_ and _descend_ **should** be the same.

Comment: @WS2 _Ascension_ and _ascent_ are often used interchangeably in secular contexts. For example, a rise to stardom may be described as either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words *[ascension](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ascension&allowed_in_frame=0), [ascent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ascent&allowed_in_frame=0), [descension](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=descension&allowed_in_frame=0),* and *[descent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=descent&allowed_in_frame=0)* all ultimately derive from the Latin root *scandere* “to climb,” through different routes.

*Ascension* (c.1300) and *descension* (early 15c.) are both derived transparently from Latin *ascensionem* and *descensionem,* nouns of action formed from the past participles of *ascendere* and *descendere.*

*Descent* (c.1300) is filtered through Old French *descente* “descent, descendance, lineage”; *ascent* (c.1610) is derived from English *ascend* by analogy with *descent/descend.*

The words are close enough in meaning and etymology to mix and match them as synonyms and antonyms for most senses, although *ascension* has religious senses that *ascent* does not, and *descent* has genealogical senses that *descension* does not. *Descension* is less often paired with *ascension* simply because the word [isn’t much used in English at all](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ascension,%20descension,%20ascent,%20descent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,ascension;,c0;.t1;,descension;,c0;.t1;,ascent;,c0;.t1;,descent;,c0).

Comment: Very helpful! +1 for the Google ngram reference.

Comment: But I am still waiting for a sentence which contains the word ascension in a secular sense! How about: 'When I flew from Singapore to London recently, I was astonished that the Airbus A380, the world's largest (double-decker) airliner, powered by four Rolls Royce Trents, with over 600 passengers and enough fuel on board for a 13 hour flight, did the runway to 25,000 feet in under 9 minutes. That seemed to an engineeringly uneducated person like me,  a remarkable rate of ascension'?

Comment: I would use _ascent_ for that. Try this instead: “Fan are thrilled with Jennifer Lawrence's ascension to superstardom.”

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think? Monarchs ascend to the throne, our present Queen's ascension having been in 1952. But the opposite is not 'descension', it is death or abdication! 'Descension' is not in Oxford Dictionaries.